# How to make Facebook app status from live to development if it's type is business?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

I'm unable to change the status of an app from live to development mode. I can't see that status toggle on the app dashboard. My app type is business. How can I change the status of this app?

I'm unable to change the status of this app from Iive to development mode this app is of type business. and it's not showing a toggle to switch the app status. I have also seen business assets but there I'm also not able to find where I can change the app status.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test#app-modes: _"Apps that have chosen the Business app type do not have app modes at all and instead rely on access levels, which behave similarly."_

Comment: How we can make it public or unpublic?